# How to return custom parameter from IdentityServer3 login page?

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver3

I needed to implement custom capcha for our login page. So I have extended/overrided custom ViewServiceBase and DefaultUserService. By now I can pass custom parameters from CustomUserService to my login.html and thus pass captcha image and id to it. However I cannot pass any custom data to CustomViewService so I cannot verify captcha input. Solution would be extend LocalAuthenticationContext and use it. Or is there any other way how to pass data from login.html to CustomUserService please?

We cannot use blacbox/not trusworthy captchas like reCaptcha because of policy.

I am not providing you with code snippets, because my implementation varies very little from original code and difference is irrelevant to my question.

Thanks for any hint, even for dirty ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `OwinEnvironmentService` into your user service and that will give you access to the form post body.